# how to send error message to view when authorization failed in Lavavel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a system in which user can join a group. User can make an ajax request if he full fill the two conditions

- he must be logged in
- he don't join this chamber before

I am currently save error messages in sessions. If the user is not logged in I wanted to do a particular task in view else if the user already join the group the I wanted to do a particular task in view.

That is my authentication code which run before the controller method

```
    public function authorize()
{

    //authorize that user must be logged in
   if(session()->get('uid')!=NULL){
      //authorize that user must not join this group before 
      $status=Usergroup::where(['user_id'=>session()->get('uid'), 
      'group_id'=>$this->chamber_id])->exists();

       if($status){
           session()->put('join_group_auth_error','already_joined');
           return false;
       }
       else{

           return true;
       }

       }
       else{
        session()->put('join_group_auth_error','not_login');
        return false;
       }
}
```

this is the ajax request

```
  function joinChamber(chamber_id){

    $.ajax({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },

        url:'{{route('join.group')}}',
        type:'post',
        data:{group_id:group_id},
        success:function(response,status){
            if(response=='joined'){
             $("#joinbuttondiv-"+chamber_id).html('<span 
             class="bodybadge">Joined</span>');
             }},


        error:function(response){
        if(response.status==403){

        @if(session()->get('join_group_auth_error')=='not_login') 
            {{session()->forget('join_group_auth_error')}}
            openRegisterModal();

            @elseif(session()- 
            >get('join_group_auth_error')=='already_joined')
            {{session()->forget('join_group_auth_error')}}
            alert('You have already joined this group.');
            window.location=window.location.href;

            @endif

        }

    }
    });
```

**This system work fine, but not every time.**
for example i am on the view from which i have to make an ajax request and i am not logged in. When i click on join button, **nothing happen**, but after refreshing the page when i click on the join button it happen that i want. **What's the reason behind this**.
Also tell me is it the exact way to do this?

Comment: Ajax cant reload the page thats the issue

Comment: There is no need to reload the page. Actually after refresing the page i again click on the join button and then it work fine.

Comment: can you show me console log error??

Comment: it is an error with status 403.

POST http://localhost/webproject/public/thegroup/joingroup 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

see console in browser and click on error (red)link, it shows you server errors - what problem has been occurred.

Comment: I wanted to perform actions again errors...read the question carefully